# The function $G:\mathbb{Q}^n \rightarrow \mathsf{FinGroup}$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

Consider the function $G:\mathbb{Q}^{n} \rightarrow \mathsf{FinGroup}$ which sends $\langle a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}\rangle$ via the polynomial $P(x) = a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1x + a_0$ to its Galois group.

How does this function partition $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$?

---

**Edit:** A little more thinking led me to the conclusion that it might be more appropriate to consider functions $G:\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{P}^{n} \rightarrow \mathsf{FinGroup}$ with $\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{P}^{n}$ something like the rational [projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space) with points = straight lines in $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$ going through the origin, due to the fact that $G(\vec{a}) = G(c\vec{a})$ for each $c \in \mathbb{Q}\setminus \{0\}$.

Does the following still make sense then (replacing $\mathbb{Q}^n$ by $\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{P}^{n}$)? Can we do epsilontics in projective spaces?

---

There may be $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{Q}^{n}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ with $G(\vec{a}) = G(\vec{b})$ for all $\vec{b}$ with $|\vec{a}-\vec{b}| < \epsilon$, and there may be $\vec{a}$ for which this doesn't hold. There even may be isolated points $\vec{a}$ such that for **no** $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\vec{b}$ with $|\vec{a}-\vec{b}| < \epsilon$ and $G(\vec{a}) = G(\vec{b})$.

Can I somehow imagine this partition, resp. the shapes of the borders between regions with constant $G$? The first non-trivial case is $n = 4$ for cubic polynomials having three possible Galois groups: the trivial group, $S_3$ and $A_3$. What can be said about the "distribution" of these three groups over $\mathbb{Q}^{4}$?

Comment: nice question. I know this paper gives an answer over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (using the $p$-adic absolute value, of course). The references might have hints at what's true over $\mathbb{Q}$ for the archimdean absolute value, but I imagine the general answer is difficult: https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0555

Comment: Is your definition of an isolated point really what you want? Perhaps you mean "points $\vec{a}$ such that for no $\epsilon>0$ is $G(\vec{a})=G(\vec{b})$ for all $\vec{b}$ with $|\vec{a}-\vec{b}|<\epsilon$". As stated, this would imply that $\vec{a}$ is the only point with the Galois group $G(\vec{a})$.

Comment: I wanted to say: "the only point with $G(\vec{a})$ in its arbitrary close neighbourhood". How to capture this?

Comment: Perhaps clearest is "for some $\epsilon>0$, each $\vec{b}$ with $|\vec{a}-\vec{b}|<\epsilon$ has $G(\vec{a})\ne G(\vec{b})$.

Comment: @HansStricker the space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$, modulo rational equivalence, identifies naturally with $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$, which is a subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R}$ and naturally inherits the Riemannian metric of it, so I would say the new question makes sense.